# Django admin interface missing css styling in production

Tags: django, nginx, deployment

The user interface is working well, and all CSS styling and static files are served correctly, but the admin interface is missing CSS styling. I looked at similar posts but in those posts people had the issue with both the user and the admin interface. My issue is only with the admin interface.

Please see my static file settings below from `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#Location of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]

STATIC_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

And this is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/MYUSERNAME/myproject;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/MYUSERNAME/myproject;
    }
```

I already executed `python manage.py collectstatic` on the server and got this message:

```
0 static files copied to '/home/MYUSERNAME/myproject/staticfiles', 255 unmodified.
```

I restarted nginx after that and also tried emptying my browser cache, but the issue persisted.

**More info as requested by @Omar Siddiqui.**
Using Django 3.2
My mysite/urls.py contains:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

# Imports to configure media files for summernote editor
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('qa.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('chatbot/', include('chatbot.urls')),
]

# Enable media files for summernote editor
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to host my Django app. Ended up just finding the admin css files and pasting them with the rest of the static files. So if all else fails you have that option.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Will keep that as a last bullet :)

Comment: @MarkoBorković I have been doing that since yesterday but there is just a lot of static files that need to be manually copy-pasting. I have the summernote WYSIWYG editor and that has a lot of small SVG icons and other stuff, so it's becoming very impractical.

Comment: What version of Django are you using, and can you post your urls.py file(s) as well?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui ok, please see the edits added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you please try below steps and let me know if it's working or not?

**Apply below changes in settings.py file:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**Remove below line from your settings.py:**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

**Execute below command in production:**

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

**Update nginx file like below one:**

```
# prevent css, js files sent as text/plain objects
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        root /home/MYUSERNAME/myproject;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        root /home/MYUSERNAME/myproject;
    }
}
```

**Explanations:**

- `STATIC_ROOT` is the folder where static files will be stored after
  using `python manage.py collectstatic`
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the list of folders where django will search for additional static files aside from the `static` folder of each app installed.

In this case our concern was Admin related CSS files that why we use `STATIC_ROOT` instead of `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: That worked! Could you perhaps add some explanation on the code you provided in your answer?

Comment: It does remove the static files if I apply your suggested changes to my local settings.py file on localhost, but that is a different problem.

Comment: I add a small explanation for you @multigoodverse. If you need any further details then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `STATIC_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` to:

```
STATIC_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Then re-run `python manage.py collectstatic`. This has worked in the past for some people

Comment: So, I tried changing `staticfiles` to `static` in the production server and then run `python manage.py collectstatic` but I get this error: `SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.
`

Comment: @omar, You are wrong ! static root and static dir should not be same :)

Comment: Its Worked form me.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an alias to the static location in nginx, like so:

```sh
location /static/ {
    alias /home/MYUSERNAME/myproject/staticfiles/
}
```

Don't forget to restart nginx afterwards.